# How to replace a button?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, button, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I wrote the following code to replace the "Add to cart" (Ajouter au panier) button with a "Offline sales" button.

It does not work. Instead of replacing the button, he adds a new one.

How to replace the button "Add to cart" ?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Hook implementations of commerce_add_to_cart_access module.
 */

use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductType;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationType;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function commerce_add_to_cart_access_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Code to get store owner.
  $current_store = \Drupal::service('commerce_store.current_store');
  $owner = $current_store->getStore()->getOwner();
  if (!$owner->hasRole('marchand_premium')) {
    // Overwrite the whole form markup.
    unset ($form['submit'])
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'inline_template',
      '#template' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Offline sales</button>',
    ];
  }
}
```

https://www.s1biose.com/produit/savon-artisanal-bio-la-cannelle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8aKq.png)

Comment: I found a little guide on drupal form altering [Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.x). I hope it will help you fix your problem a bit. Also as far as i understand it `commerce_add_to_cart_access_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter` should be something like `commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form_alter` , but here i may be wrong

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I think this part of the code is correct. You must specify the module name customize at the beginning

Comment: I looked carefully with Inspector and the page that loads has no module `commerce_add_to_cart_access_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form` or even something that is close to the name. But the page does have `commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form_alter` as a part of the `class` property of the form.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I do not know the php code well, can you answer with the complete code ? thank you

Comment: In two weeks, maybe even more, I never worked with Drupal. I'll have to read up on it just like you. Also my answer wont be full anyway, because I won't be able to recreate your site on a localhost. I can only give you a recommendation based on what i see in Inspector and what i found about Drupal function naming in about 5 minutes. I suggest you explore the link in my first comment, it may help you. Also read about Drupal in general.